# Unable to connect to Outlook with Sharepoint list calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-list

[image: List calendar ribbon from Sharepoint]My team have a SharePoint list calendar that they would like to view in Outlook. The links I have read elsewhere suggest that this can be done through an option on the ribbon "Connect to Outlook". But this option is missing from my ribbon. Is there a setting that I need turned on to be able to have this option? If so, how?
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your ribbon

Comment: updated with screen shot

Comment: Was this list created as a Calendar list or is it just a regular list with an added Calendar View added?

Comment: It's a regular list with a Calendar View added

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
1.Open Internet Explorer

2.Click on Tools at the top and select Internet Options

3.Click the Security Tab

4.Click Local Intranet

5.Click Sites

6.Click Advanced and all of the intranet sites will reappear in the websites box, make sure there is a check box in the Require server verification box

7.Click Close

8.Click Ok

9.Click Ok [done]
```

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/809674/connect-to-outlook-button-missing-from-sharepoint